# Customize margin between paragraphs using the Gutenberg Style editor

Tags: css, block-editor, editor

I'm using the new Styles editor to customize the theme. I would like to change the spacing between the paragraphs of the page and single templates. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if your theme supports full site editing. This is using Wordpress 6.1.

1. From the admin, go to Appearance > Editor.
2. At the very top of the editor you will see the current template being edited. Click the little dropdown arrow next to that and then "Browse all Templates".
3. From the list of templates, click on Single or Page.
4. Click on the "styles" icon in the top right (looks like a half moon).
5. In the right hand panel, click on Blocks > Paragraph > Layout.
6. Click on the paperclip/link icon next to "padding" to allow you to set just vertical spacing without affecting horizontal spacing.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, though it modifies all the `p` blocks on the whole page, some of which are in the header and footer. I want just the page content paragraphs to have additional margin or padding.